# Finding files of certain extensions like *.svg,*.jpg,*.sketch and moving them into specific folder structure. Using Mac Automator

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, automator

I am new to automator in mac. I am just messing around it to see if i can get the expected result for this issue i am having:

*"I am a designer and i have to download loads of files from internet for references and hence my downloads folder gets messy and i wanted to organize it in a specific way. Like i have files like jpg, svg, eps, sketch, etc. I have the following folder structure created, and i want the some kind of automation to move the files of respective extesnsion to respective folder in the folder structure as they get added to the downloads folder the first time itself. Hence i was looking for options and i found the automator can be used for this."*

Folder Structure as follows

> - Animations
>
>   - Keynotes
>   - Principle
>   - Design Files
>   - Affinity Files
>   - Sketch Files
>   - Desktop
>   - Documents
>   - Fonts
>   - Images
>   - Icons
>
>     - ICNS
>     - ICO
>     - ICONSET
>   - Raster
>
>     - JPG
>     - PNG
>     - Other
>   - Vector
>
>     - EPS
>     - SVG
>   - Other Files
>   - Softwares
>   - Videos

I tried creating folder actions in the automator for this. I added the following conditions

> - Find Finder Items
>
>   - Input = Downloads folder    Search = Computer    Condition = all /    any    depending on my need for the respective folder structure
>       criteria = file extension IS jpg/png/svg/eps/ etc based on my need.
> - Move Finder Item
>
>   - To = Specific folder based on the respective extension.

I tried creating a single script with all the conditions like if-else / switch statement like:
If extension is .jpg move it to Image>Raster>Jpg folder
If extension is .svg move it to Image>Vector>SVG folder
etc,.. etc,..

Single file with data:
[image]

But it was not working properly. It was moving files randomly to random folders.

Then i created seperate rules for seperate files but they still behave the same way. Not sure why.

Could someone help me out on this?

Comment: You've set the search scope of your **Find Finder Items** to search your ***entire computer***. You don't want to do that…  On top of that, I suspect the previous searches are sending their results into all of the subsequent actions that follow.  After the item has been moved, you can choose an option to have the next **Find Finder Itmes** _ignore_ the previous action's input, which might be prudent. But, generally, Automator building-block actions are slow, not very intuitive, and generally awful for this kind of thing. I suggest using a **Run Shell Script** or **Run AppleScript** action.

Comment: Or not using Automator at all, and creating Folder Actions using AppleScript.

Comment: Note that a folder action (Automator or AppleScript) has the dropped items passed to the workflow, so searching the folder again shouldn't be needed.

Comment: I tried the ignore input option too. Sill it does put the files into different folders rather than how it is expected. This was really a strange behaviour.

Comment: For the apple script can you please provide me an example of how one set should be i will figure out the same for the rest of inputs. Sorry if this is blatant. 